# Book or novel with a man that exchanges his sword for an army

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember seeing an animation on YouTube about a book or novel where a man exchanges a magic sword for an army, stating something like that an army has more use or something.

I believe that the sword he traded was something of immense power and the action was questionable or something.

Comment: Something very related happens in *The Stormlight Archive: The Way of Kings*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is likely *The Way of Kings*, first book of the *Stormlight Archive*, by Brandon Sanderson.

Dalinar and Sadeas are rival lords and generals trying to fight a war against an enemy that assassinated their king. The key to their power lies in Shardblades, old magical relics that cut through anything except other Shards (or Shardplate which is just as rare). Dalinar spends the book trying to get the lords to work together to end the war, and Sadeas just finished backstabbing him and leaving him to die in the field.  Dalinar was saved by a team of slaves (led by Kaladin) that run bridges across chasms for Sadeas.  Dalinar trades his Shardblade (which Sadeas is greedy for) for all of Sadeas' slaves, saving them from his likely retribution.

From the book:

> Dalinar took one step forward, then drove his Blade point-first into the middle of the blackened glyph on the stone. He took a step back. “For the bridgemen,” he said.

> Sadeas blinked. Muttering voices fell silent, and the people on the field seemed too stunned, even, to breathe.

> “What?” Sadeas asked.

> “The Blade,” Dalinar said, firm voice carrying in the air. “In exchange for your bridgemen. All of them. Every one you have in camp. They become mine, to do with as I please, never to be touched by you again. In exchange, you get the sword.”

> Sadeas looked down at the Blade, incredulous. “This weapon is worth fortunes. Cities, palaces, kingdoms.”

Shortly after, Dalinar tells Kaladin that he and his crew had saved thousands of priceless lives, including Dalinar and his sons, and that one priceless sword was a small price in comparison.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, that is the one yes. I couldn't remember what it was and it was driving me insane!

Comment: @Prime103 It's a REALLY good book series, and I recommend you read the 3 sequels as well as the other books set in the same universe. There are so many holy shit moments and every book has a bonkers finale that will have you at the edge of your seat, reading well past the time you've allotted.